# full-screen browser window on load document

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, dom-events

How can I full-screen browser window after loading the page?
I have used code like below in jQuery but its working only using the event **click**;
but I want that to be worked on **load**.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    function fullScreen(){
            var docElm = document.documentElement;
            if (docElm.requestFullscreen) {
                //alert("requestFullscreen");
                docElm.requestFullscreen();
            }
            else if (docElm.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                //alert("mozRequestFullScreen");
                docElm.mozRequestFullScreen();
            }
            else if (docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                //alert("webkitRequestFullScreen");
                docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen();
            }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

from https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko:FullScreenAPI#Suggested_UA_Policy

> ..requestFullScreen while the window is already in the full-screen state is approved.
>       Otherwise, requestFullScreen **outside a user action** (e.g. a non-synthesized input event handler) **is denied.**

so it's not possible force a fullscreen if it's not triggered by a user action

Comment: can I not make a button and then programmatically "trigger" that button? :) I'm also trying to build a web app that opens in full screen...