# To call Dofullscreen function immediately after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following is the script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            function DoFullScreen() {

                var isInFullScreen = (document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) ||    // alternative standard method  
                (document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen);

                var docElm = document.documentElement;
                if (!isInFullScreen) {

                    if (docElm.requestFullscreen) {
                        docElm.requestFullscreen();
                    }
                    else if (docElm.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                        docElm.mozRequestFullScreen();
                        //alert("Mozilla entering fullscreen!");
                    }
                    else if (docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                        docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen();
                        alert("Webkit entering fullscreen!");
                    }
                }
            }

        </script>
```

HTML

```
<body onload="DoFullScreen()">
    <form id="form1" runat="server" >
        <div id="div1">
            <input id="bt1" type="button" value="button"   />
            Hello
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

I have tried

1. `$(window).load`
2. `$(document).ready(function(){    $("#bt1").load`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-- it's not possible force a fullscreen if it's not triggered by a user action

-- look at this

[full-screen browser window on load document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352236/full-screen-browser-window-on-load-document)

Comment: No, why should there be? Browsers do have popup blockers today because users where bothered by stupid website authors (and advertisers) too much – and you are trying to do the same thing, take control over something that is and should be under the user’s control.

Answer (score 0):

on ready call your function

> $(document).ready(function(){
>
> DoFullScreen();
>
> }

Comment: Yes the trouble is you are calling the function DoFullScreen before that piece of html has even been parsed and loaded into the DOM!  The jQuery "ready" shown in Mastermind's answer waits until everything has been loaded in before executing your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using pure `javascript` only like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {

                // YOUR CODE STUFF 

                }
</script>
```

Comment: Check it by using alert if the function is called or not after the page is loaded. It should work.

Comment: window.onload = function() { alert('Test'); } works well for me. So please check for errors inside the function too.

Comment: Ok so put you codes inside the function `DoFullScreen()` directly into the function as you put `alert('hi')`. How are you doing it?

Comment: see link of @user2351467...it will work for other function but not for this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29531/discussion-between-somnath-kharat-and-kishor-subedi)