# How to fire a function on page load with javascript the right way?

Tags: javascript

Checked quite a lot of info also on stackoverflow, like in here [How do I call a JavaScript function on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842614/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-on-page-load)

but still I get problems firing the function on load. I have this one:

http://jsbin.com/agopuv/2/

Code is in here: http://jsbin.com/agopuv/2/edit

Edited: Added the ***`HTML+JS`*** codes
Here is the ***`js`*** code:

```
function toggleFullScreen() {
    if ((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) ||    
       (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
    if (document.documentElement.requestFullScreen) {  
      document.documentElement.requestFullScreen();  
    } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {  
      document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();  
    } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {  
      document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);  
    }  
  } else {  
    if (document.cancelFullScreen) {  
      document.cancelFullScreen();  
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {  
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();  
    } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {  
      document.webkitCancelFullScreen();  
    }  
  }  
} 

$(document).on('pageinit', function () {
    setTimeout(toggleFullScreen,1000);
});
```

And ***`Html`*** code:

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="click to toggle" onclick="toggleFullScreen()">
```

and it actually works only when pressed on the button, but I did not succeeded in any ways to fire the function on page load.

Any advices regarding this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Requesting full screen outside a user action is not permitted by the browser's security policy

Read the [Mozilla UA Policy](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko:FullScreenAPI#Suggested_UA_Policy)

> The specification intentionally gives UAs great freedom in policy,
>   because no one policy can fit all users, devices, and user interface
>   designs. However, here is a policy that should be acceptable for
>   conventional desktop browsers.
>
> - requestFullScreen while the window is already in the full-screen    state is approved.
> - Otherwise, requestFullScreen outside a user action    (e.g. a non-synthesized input event handler) is denied.
> - Otherwise,    requestFullScreen without the ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT flag is approved.
> - Otherwise, passive confirmation UI is presented and requestFullScreen    is approved if and when the user approves it.

Also see a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352236/full-screen-browser-window-on-load-document)