# Automatic browser full screen switch on document load / ready

Tags: jquery, browser, fullscreen

I am trying to switch the browser to full screen on document load. Among the various plugins available I tried to work with [this](https://github.com/kayahr/jquery-fullscreen-plugin). The API suggests that full screen mode can be entered like `$(document).fullScreen(true);`

The API works correctly on a button click. However, if I try to trigger the click via jQuery,   it fails.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#wow').click(function(){
            $(document).fullScreen(true);
        });

        $('#wow').trigger('click');

    })
```

Tried to just do a `$(document).fullScreen(true);` on document.ready, it still fails.
Both actually fail with a `Full screen error.`

Triggering the button manually works!

The example code provided has code like these:

```
 <button onclick="$(document).fullScreen(true)">Enter Fullscreen mode (Document)</button>
```

They work on manual clicks.

I am unable to understand why the same code fails to work if the event is fired programmatically.

Please advice.

---

### EDIT:

I saw this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352236/full-screen-browser-window-on-load-document?rq=1), which suggests that programmatic switching is "denied" [if i got it right]. So, is there any work-around for this?

Comment: It's a security restriction. You can't go around it without user interaction (installing browser extension, clicking on buttons etc)

Comment: Your user must initiate the full screen switch.  Therefore it works when done from a button click, but not automatically on document ready/window load.

Just imagine all the annoying popup windows/ads we'd have if this would be allowed!  Thank god it isn't!