# F11 key event fire on onload using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to fire <kbd>F11</kbd> key event onload and automatic exit from that after some action.?

Comment: Can you provide a specific example of what you want to do? This isn't clear enough, and is liable to be closed as "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: Answers on this question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424407/handling-key-press-events-f1-f12-using-javascript-and-jquery-cross-browser

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863351/checking-if-browser-is-in-fullscreen

Comment: I want to make one demo using sets of images so when user come on webpage than fullscreen will be automatically come and demo should be start.After demo over automatically exit full screen mode.

Comment: Here you can find some help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19856794/automatic-browser-full-screen-switch-on-document-load-ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your following code on your load event:

```
 if ((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) || (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
           if (document.documentElement.requestFullScreen) {
                document.documentElement.requestFullScreen();
            } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
            } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
            }
        } else {
            if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
                document.cancelFullScreen();
            } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
                document.mozCancelFullScreen();
            } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
                document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
            }
        }
```

It will able to re-size of your window screen to device screen.

Comment: Not working in Chrome :(